# How to travel between Las Vegas and Death Valley by public transportation?

Tags: usa, public-transport, las-vegas, death-valley

Learning that February is a good time to visit the Death Valley, I decided to pay a visit there with a bunch of friends from LA. The friends are driving from LA to the Death Valley, and I am traveling to the Death Valley from Las Vegas -- yes, we are meeting up at the Death Valley.

I can't drive. Since inside the Death Valley, we prefer to travel ourselves, I cannot join any organized tour from Vegas to the Death Valley. So I have to take public transportation from Vegas to the Valley and back.

Is it even possible? If so, how should I do this?

---

Thanks @Greg for citing the information that no public transportation from Vegas to the Valley is available. The least thing I want to do is to ask my friends to drive to Vegas to pick me up. That is a huge detour. So I did some math.

[image]

The figure shows the route from LA to the Valley. What if I go towards LA direction along 15 and wait for them to pass by and pick me up in the car? This turning point is a town called Baker, CA. I checked Greyhound from Las Vegas to Baker, CA. There is none either. Any solution to this situation so far?

Comment: The greyhound service from Las Vegas to Los Angeles makes a stop at Barstow, CA. Perhaps you could meet your friends there.

Comment: Be careful out there, and remember it's called Death Valley for a good reason. Here's an example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Valley_Germans

Comment: @RobertFurber That's a bit of fear mongering.  The average high in DV in July is 116ºF.  The average high when the OP is traveling in Feb is 74ºF.  The average lows are 88ºF and 46ºF respectively.  So Feb is positively balmy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I searched Google for "las vegas to death valley bus" and found [this page on about.com](http://gocalifornia.about.com/od/cadeathvalley/ss/las-vegas-to-death-valley.htm) which says:

> There are no public transportation options between Las Vegas and Death Valley, but you can take the Bundu Bus, which travels through Death Valley four times a week on its way from Las Vegas to Yosemite. [Get the details on the Bundu Bus website](http://www.bundubus.com/death_valley_transportation.php). Without some other means of getting around once you reach Death Valley, you won't be able to see much while you're there, though.

Comment: Note that Bundu Bus can drop you off in Death Valley if you wish.  They won't guarantee _where_ unless it's at lodging they book for you.